# Additive Blending in custom shader

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have two custom shader materials which I would like to blend additively.  Changing the blending option in the material is not having any effect.  Do I need to add something to the shaders themselves?  If so, are there an example I might follow from somewhere?

[image: Incorrect Blending]

Comment: It is hard to know what's happening here, but at first glance it looks like z-fighting. Why not turn depth off?

Comment: Yeah I thought that, but this effect happens regardless of the distance between the two elements so its not that. Turning depth off isn't an option in this case anyway unfortunately.

Comment: The coloured strips always block out the spherical glows. I'd like them to additively combine if possible

Comment: still hard to know what you really want but have you considered using `renderOrder` to force the glowing part to render last?

Comment: Yeah I just need it to white-out really so that might work. I'll give it a go...

Comment: so renderDepth doesn't work unless depthTest is off on the material. I need these two objects to be obscured by a third else the scene look totally broken.

Comment: I'm after the additive blending effect seen here where additional colours just add brightness http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_blending.html

Comment: `renderOrder` is not `renderDepth`-- if your renderer has sorting on, then you can assign each object a renderOrder value, e.g. `myMesh.renderOrder=4;" and the renderer will draw higher-numbered meshes after lower ones -- even if they were farther away. If you turn off `myMesh.material.dethTest=false;` then that mesh will transparently render over the others while ignoring their relative depths, because you've set its `renderOrder` to a higher value than the default (0)